# Google Analytics and anonymizeIp

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, privacy

I have set up Google Analytics and received this tracking code here

```html
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-********-1', '*****.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

But I also need to implement the **anonymizeIp** function because of legal issues. It sais [*here*](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gat) that you have a `_gat` object and just have to call that function. But in the tracking code I received, there is no `_gat` object.

I've also seen code snippets related to this issue which look completely different than my tracking code.

**The burning question is:** How do I implement the anonymizeIp in my tracking code correctly?

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker installed? Have you tried clearing your cache? Either of these could be preventing _gat from loading/existing

Comment: That's not what I meant. The problem is that I don't know how to actually implement this method to my existing code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using the newer Universal Analytics (`analytics.js`) code, which has a different syntax. Try

```
ga('create', 'UA-********-1', '*****.com');
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Docs at: [IP Anonymization](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced?hl=en#anonymizeip)

Comment: @mike Looks like the url to the docs you are referring to has been changed to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ip-anonymization

Answer (score 2):

Could be a timing issue, I found this solution on Google's forums (http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/K8yFv5XBtCM), added in the anonmyizeIp method to resolve your issue:

```
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var pageTracker; 
setTimeout('startGA();', 500); 
function startGA() 
{ 
    pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXX-X"); 
    pageTracker._initData();
    pageTracker._anonymizeIp();
    pageTracker._trackPageview(); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Should I replace my tracking code with this code or should I add this to my existing code?

Comment: Well, it looks like Mike might be correct on this one. With mine you would not need to replace your tracking code, only add the second script block to your page.